# Standards of "clean" for artifacts launched into space

Tags: spacecraft, forward-contamination

When the Viking landers, and the Sojourner, Spirit, Opportunity, and Curiosity rovers were built and prepared for launch, they would have had to be made as free of Earth microbes (living or not) as possible so as not to introduce contamination into the environments they were exploring for signs of Martian life.

On the other hand, it's impractical/impossible/unnecessary to prepare an entire launch vehicle in this way, because it's in contact with Earth's atmosphere on the way up, and much of it won't get anywhere near a target environment e.g. surface of Mars anyway.

My question is: what sort of considerations/requirements exist for spacecraft, including something like Starman, which although not predicted to ever impact Mars, can't be assumed to *never* do so? After all, as his personal car, the Tesla must have been teeming with Earth bacteria, as everything else in our everyday world is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_protection or https://planetaryprotection.nasa.gov/about